# Unable to get ClipboardJS to copy QuillJS editor content

Tags: asp.net, quill

I retrieve a JSON string to a hidden field in Razor Page.  In script, I parse the string and convert object properties to Delta object, and finally set the contents of the Quill editor with the Delta instance.  Clicking the copy button appears to select the contents of the editor but nothing happens when I paste.

I have very similar code in another program where it works but I am unable to spot the significant difference.  In both programs the content is dynamically generated in JavaScript.  I am stumped and in hope of a clue.

Sample of what is to be copied:
[image]

JavaScript:

```
new ClipboardJS('.copy');
// make styles inline to work in Epic note
let Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');

class BoldStyleAttributor extends Parchment.Attributor.Style {
    value(domNode) {
        let value = super.value(domNode);
        return value;
    }

    add(node) {
        $(node).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        return true;
    }

    remove(node) {
        $(node).css('font-weight', 'normal');
    }
}

const BoldStyle = new BoldStyleAttributor('bold', 'font-weight', {
    scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE
});

Quill.register(BoldStyle, true);

class ItalicStyleAttributor extends Parchment.Attributor.Style {
    value(domNode) {
        let value = super.value(domNode);
        return value;
    }

    add(node) {
        $(node).css('font-style', 'italic');
        return true;
    }

    remove(node) {
        $(node).css('font-style', 'normal');
    }
}

const ItalicStyle = new ItalicStyleAttributor('italic', 'font-style', {
    scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE
});

Quill.register(ItalicStyle, true);

class UnderlineStyleAttributor extends Parchment.Attributor.Style {
    value(domNode) {
        let value = super.value(domNode);
        return value;
    }

    add(node) {
        $(node).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        return true;
    }

    remove(node) {
        $(node).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
}

const UnderlineStyle = new UnderlineStyleAttributor('underline', 'text-decoration', {
    scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE
});

Quill.register(UnderlineStyle, true);

var ColorStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/color');
Quill.register(ColorStyle, true);

const fontSizeArr = ['10px', '12px', false, '14px', '16px', '18px', '24px'];
let fontSize = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
fontSize.whitelist = fontSizeArr;
Quill.register(fontSize, true);

const fontFamilyArr = ["Arial", "Calibri", "Calibri Light", "Courier New", "Georgia", "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Times New Roman", "Verdana"];
let fonts = Quill.import("attributors/style/font");
fonts.whitelist = fontFamilyArr;
Quill.register(fonts, true);

const toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],        // toggled buttons
    [{ 'font': fontFamilyArr }],
    [{ 'size': fontSizeArr }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ 'color': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
];

const properties = {
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
};

setTooltips();
let strqrs = $('#Qrs').val();
let ntObj = JSON.parse(strqrs);
$('#Qrs').val('');
let Delta = Quill.import('delta');
let delta = new Delta();
for (let i = 0; i < ntObj.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        delta.insert(ntObj[i].TitleTop, { size: "16px", bold: true }).insert(ntObj[i].Resps);
    }
    else {
        delta.insert(ntObj[i].Title, { size: "16px", bold: true }).insert(ntObj[i].Resps);
    }
    if (i == ntObj.length - 1) {
       let nt = new Quill("#QrNote", properties);
       nt.setContents(delta);
    }
}
```

Razor View

```
@model StrQrs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Note";
    string btnLabel = $"Copy form data for Jane Doe on {@ViewBag.DT}";
}
<div class="copybtn">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Qrs" />
    <button type="button" class="copy btn btn-outline-dark" data-clipboard-target="#QrNote">@btnLabel</button>
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    <div id="QrNote" style="overflow-y:auto; height:600px; max-height:600px;width:900px;max-width:900px"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        initNote();
    });
</script>
```